# What does O(log n) mean exactly?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning about Big O Notation running times and amortized times.  I understand the notion of *O(n)* linear time, meaning that the size of the input affects the growth of the algorithm proportionally...and the same goes for, for example, quadratic time *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* etc..even algorithms, such as permutation generators, with *O(n!)* times, that grow by factorials.

For example, the following function is *O(n)* because the algorithm grows in proportion to its input *n*:

```
f(int n) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Similarly, if there was a nested loop, the time would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

But what exactly is *O(log n)*?  For example, what does it mean to say that the height of a complete binary tree is *O(log n)*?

I do know (maybe not in great detail) what Logarithm is, in the sense that:  log<sub>10</sub> 100 = 2, but I cannot understand how to identify a function with a logarithmic time.

Comment: A 1-node binary tree has height log2(1)+1 = 1, a 2-node tree has height log2(2)+1 = 2, a 4-node tree has height log2(4)+1 = 3, and so on. An n-node tree has height log2(n)+1, so adding nodes to the tree causes its average height to grow logarithmically.

Comment: One thing I'm seeing in most answers is that they essentially describe "O(something)" means the running time of the algorithm grows in proportion to "something". Given that you asked for "exact meaning" of "O(log n)", it's not true. That's the intuitive description of Big-Theta notation, not Big-O. O(log n) intuitively means the running time grows **at most** proportional to "log n": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on/471206#471206

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/487278#487278

Comment: I always remember divide and conquer as the example for O(log n)

Comment: Trickiness about your function: It's linear with respect to the VALUE of the input, however - if we think of n as a vector of bits (how we represent the input) - it's actually O(2^n) in terms of the SIZE of the input (ie. it takes lg(n) bits to represent n, so if n is k bits long, the loop iterates up to 2^k times). So I would say that loop is exponential, not linear.

Comment: It's important to realize that its log base 2 (not base 10). This is because at each step in an algorithm, you remove half of your remaining choices. In computer science we almost always deal with log base 2 because we can ignore constants. However there are some exceptions (i.e. Quad Tree run times are log base 4)

Comment: @Ethan: It doesn't matter which base you are in, since base conversion is just a constant multiplication, The formula is log_b(x) = log_d(x) / log_d(b). Log_d(b) will just be a constant.

Comment: Few basic information about logarithms!
1.[Demystifying the Natural Logarithm](http://betterexplained.com/articles/demystifying-the-natural-logarithm-ln/)                                                                                                                            

2.[Using Logarithms in the Real World](http://betterexplained.com/articles/using-logs-in-the-real-world/)

Comment: @mdkess Yes I know it is a constant factor, I even said so in my comment. I was pointing out that logarithmic run times often involve dividing your choices in half as opposed to a log base 10 run time which would involve removing 9/10ths of your choices at each step. So I was pointing out to the OP that we often find ourselves dividing our choices in half at each step of some algorithm, which results in a log base 2 run time not log base 10. Realizing that is useful to being able to look at code and say "Oh that's O(logn)". I was not really saying anything about actual run time.

Comment: @Ethan: You're still incorrect. If something is O(log_b(n)), b > 1, it is O(log_c(n)) for any c > 1. So dividing your choices in half results in O(log_2(n)) time AND O(log_10(n)) time AND O(log_12838(n)) runtime. It doesn't matter. Logarithm base conversion is a constant multiplication, which is dominated by the logarithm function - ie. O(c*f(n)) is O(f(n)) if c is a constant.

Comment: @mdkess I am not going for algorithmic rigor I am just trying to create a mental mapping between something in code and something being O(logn). Of course by now any attempt at that being happening has been destroyed. Great. And for the record I am not wrong because I said the run time was log base 10, I did not refer to big O notation. So if you want to be all formal then it would be T(log base 10 (n)). Now if you would like to stop arguing semantics that would be great.

Comment: @Ethan: Assuming by T you mean big-Theta, then you're right - but it's also T(log base 43 (n)) and T(log base 378 (n)), by definition.

Comment: @mdkess I do not mean big Theta. T_n is the function that is the exact running time of code. For example: T_n = 5 + 8n + n^2. Big O of T_n is O(n^2)

Comment: Can someone tell where the O stands for? Output?

Comment: @clankill3r http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/107977/8613

Comment: I recently watched a video which describes Log N perfectly. It is an absolute must watch. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjDR1NBB9MU

Comment: Maybe it would be useful http://svitlanamoiseyenko.com/2016/08/30/olog-n-and-how-fast-it-is/

Answer (score 3353, accepted):

> I cannot understand how to identify a function with a log time.

The most common attributes of logarithmic running-time function are that:

- the choice of the next element on which to perform some action is one of several possibilities, and
- only one will need to be chosen.

or

- the elements on which the action is performed are digits of n

This is why, for example, looking up people in a phone book is O(log n). You don't need to check *every* person in the phone book to find the right one; instead, you can simply divide-and-conquer by looking based on where their name is alphabetically, and in every section you only need to explore a subset of each section before you eventually find someone's phone number.

Of course, a bigger phone book will still take you a longer time, but it won't grow as quickly as the proportional increase in the additional size.

---

We can expand the phone book example to compare other kinds of operations and *their* running time. We will assume our phone book has *businesses* (the "Yellow Pages") which have unique names and *people* (the "White Pages") which may not have unique names. A phone number is assigned to at most one person or business. We will also assume that it takes constant time to flip to a specific page.

Here are the running times of some operations we might perform on the phone book, from fastest to slowest:

- **O(1) (in the worst case):** Given the page that a business's name is on and the business name, find the phone number.
- **O(1) (in the average case):** Given the page that a person's name is on and their name, find the phone number.
- **O(log n):** Given a person's name, find the phone number by picking a random point about halfway through the part of the book you haven't searched yet, then checking to see whether the person's name is at that point. Then repeat the process about halfway through the part of the book where the person's name lies. (This is a binary search for a person's name.)
- **O(n):** Find all people whose phone numbers contain the digit "5".
- **O(n):** Given a phone number, find the person or business with that number.
- **O(n log n):** There was a mix-up at the printer's office, and our phone book had all its pages inserted in a random order. Fix the ordering so that it's correct by looking at the first name on each page and then putting that page in the appropriate spot in a new, empty phone book.

For the below examples, we're now at the printer's office. Phone books are waiting to be mailed to each resident or business, and there's a sticker on each phone book identifying where it should be mailed to. Every person or business gets one phone book.

- **O(n log n):** We want to personalize the phone book, so we're going to find each person or business's name in their designated copy, then circle their name in the book and write a short thank-you note for their patronage.
- **O(n<sup>2</sup>):** A mistake occurred at the office, and every entry in each of the phone books has an extra "0" at the end of the phone number. Take some white-out and remove each zero.
- **O(n · n!):** We're ready to load the phonebooks onto the shipping dock. Unfortunately, the robot that was supposed to load the books has gone haywire: it's putting the books onto the truck in a random order! Even worse, it loads all the books onto the truck, then checks to see if they're in the right order, and if not, it unloads them and starts over. (This is the dreaded **[bogo sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)**.)
- **O(n<sup>n</sup>):** You fix the robot so that it's loading things correctly. The next day, one of your co-workers plays a prank on you and wires the loading dock robot to the automated printing systems. Every time the robot goes to load an original book, the factory printer makes a duplicate run of all the phonebooks! Fortunately, the robot's bug-detection systems are sophisticated enough that the robot doesn't try printing even more copies when it encounters a duplicate book for loading, but it still has to load every original and duplicate book that's been printed.

Comment: @David Thornley » Ah, gotcha. I thought I'd made that obvious by saying "each resident or business" was getting a phonebook, but I'll edit to highlight this.

Comment: @cletus: Coincidental, I'm afraid. I picked it because phonebooks have a large N, people understand what they are and what they do, and because it's versatile as an example. Plus I got to use robots in my explanation! A win all-around. (Also, it looks like your answer was made before I was even a member on StackOverflow to begin with!)

Comment: @John: no worries. Was just curious. :)

Comment: "A mistake occurred at the office, and every entry in each of the phone books has an extra "0" at the end of the phone number. Take some white-out and remove each zero." <-- this is not order N squared. N is defined as the size of the input. The size of the input is the number of phone numbers, which is the number of numbers per book times the number of books. That's still a linear time operation.

Comment: @Billy: In this example, `N` is the number of people in a single book. Because every person in the phone book also gets their own copy of the book, there are `N` _identical_ phone books, each with `N` people in it, which is O(N^2).

Comment: @John Feminella: N, with regards to Big Oh, is always the size of the input set. If you define N to be something else, that's fine, but you did not do so above....

Comment: The bogo sort is the most stupid algorithm I have ever seen in my life. Basically `while (!isInOrder(deck)) { shuffle(deck); }`

Comment: It's a stupid algorithm, but it's not the stupidest algorithm you could possibly write. :)

Comment: @JohnFeminella I see where you’re going with the shuffled-pages example, but the description of the fix sounds like insertion sort rather than, say, mergesort or quicksort.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm people use for looking up names in phone books isn't binary search. It's interpolation search, which is O(log log n) on average!

Comment: Isn't O(1) the best case, rather than worst case as it is strangely highlighted as?

Comment: Isn't "take some white-out and remove each zero" O(n·m), where n is the number of entries, and m is the number of phonebooks printed?

Comment: @BenHodgson You are generally correct. However, in this case, since the list of customers receiving copies of the phonebook is defined as every person or business in the phonebook, n==m.

Comment: @Svip I believe the reason it was highlighted as worst case is that there is a naïve constant time process to find a given entry on a page that involves scanning every entry in order until the target entry is found. If there are 50 entries on a page, the worst case is 50 operations, which is O(1). You could potentially do better, i.e. if the target is 5th on the page. In this case, the time to do "better" is variable and unknown, since there are 49 "better" cases, but the worst case is always  a constant number of operations.

Comment: @KenB I thought O(1) meant constant time, i.e. the amount of operations is regardless of input.  50 entries taking 50 operations would be O(n).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions

Comment: @Svip O(n) implies variability. 50 operations is a fixed number if you are only considering the worst case, since the worst case is always exactly 50 entries. Honestly, it's getting into semantics a little.

Comment: Great illustration of big O notation! One comment on the O(1) case: You have a disclaimer saying that flipping to a given page number is constant time, however I think it's more like log(n). A better example for O(1) would be to pick a random phone number by flipping open a random page in the phone book and choosing a random number on that page. This has constant running time, no matter how many entries there are in the phone book, and no disclaimers required.

Comment: Quick question for the case:

"There was a mix-up at the printer's office, and our phone book had all its pages inserted in a random order. Fix the ordering so that it's correct by looking at the first name on each page and then putting that page in the appropriate spot in a new, empty phone book."

Shouldn't the complexity it should be O(n!) rather than O(n log n)

Comment: @Bagira: No; think of a deck of cards. There are `n!` ways to shuffle the cards, but it doesn't take `n!` time to sort them.

Comment: Sorry, but i could understand with cards example as well. My concern is, with Random ordering, you can't decide the subset which you need to visit. Since items are not ordered, in worst case you can move in wrong direction and will have to traverse other subset as well and every time size of list is reduced by one that's why i said n!. If you remove the word "Random" from sentence then it makes sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: It is confusing that you say, this list is in order from "best to worst" but then start the list with "worst case"

Comment: @Adam: "O(1) worst case" means that the worst it could possibly be is O(1), which is the best of all possible worlds. If you said "the worst test grade in the class was 100%", that is a very good thing, not a very bad thing!

Comment: what will be the time complexity of this function log(n!)

Comment: @Walter O(log n!) is equivalent to O(n log n).

Comment: How incredible is it that this answer has been accepted to the original question? This answer does not explain in my opinion what O(log n) time really is: you only give a lot of examples (also to things that have almost nothing to do with the question) without explaining exactly (always) why the complexity of those operations are really correct. Incredible!

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it I have provided a very simple answer for understanding O(log n)

Comment: Why does removing the last digit of each number have a complexity of O(n2)? I assumed it would be O(n).

Comment: Guys, I found solution for this Link is better to the question asked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152890/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-n-complexity/9153420#9153420

Comment: The O(n*n!) algorithm is actually unbounded - randomised bogosort is unbounded (deterministic bogosort is not) - there's no guarantee that the robot will ever finish.

Comment: The O(n^n) algorithm should more specifically be, I think, O(n^2*2^n) (because it's `n*n+2n*n+4n*n+...+n*n*2^n`, if I'm understanding it correctly, that is: we're printing n books of size n at the first step, and then reprinting the originals and the reprints). It could also use a brief explanation.

Comment: I'll just leave comment to note that binary search [is not a divide and conquer algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109411/4594973).

Comment: A Guy named John came in and banged Everything whatever comes in front of explanation  , you rock Thank you.

Comment: what does "the elements on which the action is performed are digits of n" mean

Comment: O(n · n!): We're ready to load the ...

It seems that needs to be O(n*(n-1)!)

Comment: @csguy - check out [moonshadow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307307/1057791) in this post and you'll understand it. Basically it means that if you have a number e.g. 12000 you won't preform an operation 12,000 times, but rather 5 times (because it has 5 digits). Incrementing the number will also increase the complexity but only proportionally, so if you'll increase the number to 112,000 the complexity will grow only by 1 (because now you have 6 digits), not by the actual increment which is 100,000).

Comment: Is looking for a name in phonebook *log to the base 26(n)*????? since there are 26 choices at each point.

Comment: a better example for N^2 would be that you are assigned to write everyone's phone number inside in a new phone book. you write down the numbers as 9 digit numbers, as your leaving. Your boss tells you he wants a 1- in front of each number in case there is international expansion in the future. You will have to go through every page to create these 10 digit numbers.

Answer (score 980):

`O(log N)` basically means time goes up linearly while the `n` goes up exponentially. So if it takes `1` second to compute `10` elements, it will take `2` seconds to compute `100` elements, `3` seconds to compute `1000` elements, and so on.

​It is `O(log n)` when we do divide and conquer type of algorithms e.g binary search. Another example is quick sort where each time we divide the array into two parts and each time it takes `O(N)` time to find a pivot element. Hence it  `N O(log N)`

Comment: Three lines of wisdom that beats all other essay answers... :) Just in case somebody is missing it, in programming context, the base of log is 2 (not 10), so O(log n) scales like 1 sec for 10 elements, 2 sec for 20, 3 for 40 etc.

Comment: Agreed, concise and clear, although the ending question from the OP was how to identify a logarithmic function, not quite "what is it"

Comment: yes, logarithmic function is it's inverse to exponential function. ((log x) base a) is inverse of (a power x). Qualitative analysis of these functions with graphs would give more intuition.

Comment: This took me about 3 read-throughs to realize it wasn't wrong. _Time_ goes up linearly, while the _number of elements_ is exponential. This means **more elements during less time**. This is mentally taxing for those that visualize `log` as the familiar log curve on a graph.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer, except for the part where it claims that binary search is a divide and conquer algorithm. [It isn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109411/4594973)

Comment: @ray Why is it not binary search is a divide and conquer algorithm?

Comment: @javaguy The link in my prev. comment goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109411/4594973), where I explain why it isn't. If you have further questions, please leave comment(s) under my answer within that particular post.

Comment: @nawfal That's not quite right. When you use the notation O(log n), the base of the log is irrelevant because all log functions are proportional to each other. That is why you omit the base, which is not the case with exponentials (e.g. O(2^n) is not the same as O(10^n)). So even in the context of base-2, the scaling behaviour you described is not generally correct - it depends on the constant factor.

Comment: @fastcodejava when you said divide and conquer are we assuming that x no of different thread will process the chunks?

Comment: Quick Sort's worst-case is O(n^2), while best-Case is Ω(nlogn).

Answer (score 659):

Many good answers have already been posted to this question, but I believe we really are missing an important one - namely, the illustrated answer.

> What does it mean to say that the height of a complete binary tree is O(log n)?

The following drawing depicts a binary tree. Notice how each level contains double the number of nodes compared to the level above (hence *binary*):

[image: Binary tree]

Binary search is an example with complexity `O(log n)`. Let's say that the nodes in the bottom level of the tree in figure 1 represents items in some sorted collection. Binary search is a divide-and-conquer algorithm, and the drawing shows how we will need (at most) 4 comparisons to find the record we are searching for in this 16 item dataset.

Assume we had instead a dataset with 32 elements. Continue the drawing above to find that we will now need 5 comparisons to find what we are searching for, as the tree has only grown one level deeper when we multiplied the amount of data. As a result, the complexity of the algorithm can be described as a logarithmic order.

Plotting `log(n)` on a plain piece of paper, will result in a graph where the rise of the curve decelerates as `n` increases:

[image: O(log n)]

Comment: "Notice how each level contains the double number of nodes compared to the level above (hence binary)"

This is incorrect. What you're describing is a *balanced* binary tree. A binary tree just means each node has at most two children.

Comment: In fact, it's a very special balanced binary tree, called a complete binary tree. I've edited the answer but need someone to approve it.

Comment: A complete binary tree doesn't need to have the last level to be completely filled. I would say, a 'full binary tree' is more appropriate.

Comment: Your answer tries to respond more concretely to the original problem of the OP, so it is better than the current accepted answer (IMO), but it is still very incomplete: you just give a half example and 2 images...

Comment: This tree has 31 items in it, not 16. Why is it called a 16 item data set? Every node on it represents a number, otherwise it would be an inefficient binary tree :P

Comment: I remember working with b-trees in my college programming class as a means to implement the bubble/quick sort. I was blown away by the brilliance and elegance of the solution. I have yet to find a faster sort algorithm,

Comment: "Binary search is a divide-and-conquer algorithm.." That's not so simple. I would argue it is not true. But look here and see what you think for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850447/why-is-binary-search-a-divide-and-conquer-algorithm

Answer (score 352):

**Overview**

Others have given good diagram examples, such as the tree diagrams. I did not see any simple code examples. So in addition to my explanation, I'll provide some algorithms with simple print statements to illustrate the complexity of different algorithm categories.

First, you'll want to have a general idea of Logarithm, which you can get from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm . Natural science use `e` and the natural log. Engineering disciples will use log_10 (log base 10) and computer scientists will use log_2 (log base 2) a lot, since computers are binary based. Sometimes you'll see abbreviations of natural log as `ln()`, engineers normally leave the _10 off and just use `log()` and log_2 is abbreviated as `lg()`. All of the types of logarithms grow in a similar fashion, that is why they share the same category of `log(n)`.

When you look at the code examples below, I recommend looking at O(1), then O(n), then O(n^2). After you are good with those, then look at the others. I've included clean examples as well as variations to demonstrate how subtle changes can still result in the same categorization.

You can think of O(1), O(n), O(logn), etc as classes or categories of growth. Some categories will take more time to do than others. These categories help give us a way of ordering the algorithm performance. Some grown faster as the input n grows. The following table demonstrates said growth numerically. In the table below think of log(n) as the ceiling of log_2.

[image]

**Simple Code Examples Of Various Big O Categories:**

**O(1) - Constant Time Examples:**

- **Algorithm 1:**

Algorithm 1 prints hello once and it doesn't depend on n, so it will always run in constant time, so it is `O(1)`.

```
print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 2:**

Algorithm 2 prints hello 3 times, however it does not depend on an input size. Even as n grows, this algorithm will always only print hello 3 times. That being said 3, is a constant, so this algorithm is also `O(1)`.

```
print "hello";
print "hello";
print "hello";
```

**O(log(n)) - Logarithmic Examples:**

- **Algorithm 3 - This acts like "log_2"**

Algorithm 3 demonstrates an algorithm that runs in log_2(n). Notice the post operation of the for loop multiples the current value of i by 2, so `i` goes from 1 to 2 to 4 to 8 to 16 to 32 ...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i = i * 2)
  print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 4 - This acts like "log_3"**

Algorithm 4 demonstrates log_3. Notice `i` goes from 1 to 3 to 9 to 27...

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i = i * 3)
  print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 5 - This acts like "log_1.02"**

Algorithm 5 is important, as it helps show that as long as the number is greater than 1 and the result is repeatedly multiplied against itself, that you are looking at a logarithmic algorithm.

```
for(double i = 1; i < n; i = i * 1.02)
  print "hello";
```

**O(n) - Linear Time Examples:**

- **Algorithm 6**

This algorithm is simple, which prints hello n times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 7**

This algorithm shows a variation, where it will print hello n/2 times. n/2 = 1/2 * n. We ignore the 1/2 constant and see that this algorithm is O(n).

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2)
  print "hello";
```

**O(n*log(n)) - nlog(n) Examples:**

- **Algorithm 8**

Think of this as a combination of `O(log(n))` and `O(n)`. The nesting of the for loops help us obtain the `O(n*log(n))`

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 2)
    print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 9**

Algorithm 9 is like algorithm 8, but each of the loops has allowed variations, which still result in the final result being `O(n*log(n))`

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 2)
  for(int j = 1; j < n; j = j * 3)
    print "hello";
```

**O(n^2) - n squared Examples:**

- **Algorithm 10**

`O(n^2)` is obtained easily by nesting standard for loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 11**

Like algorithm 10, but with some variations.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 2)
    print "hello";
```

**O(n^3) - n cubed Examples:**

- **Algorithm 12**

This is like algorithm 10, but with 3 loops instead of 2.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      print "hello";
```

- **Algorithm 13**

Like algorithm 12, but with some variations that still yield `O(n^3)`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < n + 5; j = j + 2)
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k = k + 3)
      print "hello";
```

**Summary**

The above give several straight forward examples, and variations to help demonstrate what subtle changes can be introduced that really don't change the analysis. Hopefully it gives you enough insight.

Comment: Awesome. The best explanation for me I ever seen. It'd be nicer if `O(n^2)` is noted as a combination of `O(n)` and `O(n)`, so `O(n) * O(n) = O(n * n) = O(n^2)`. It feels like a bit of jumping without this equation. This is repetition of prior explanation, but I think this repetition can provide more confidence to readers for understanding.

Comment: This is simply the best ever explanation.

Comment: Amazing examples! Can I ask why constants are disregarded in big O notations? Eg. why O(n/2) is simply taken as O(n)? Is it because when n --> infinity, the constant becomes insignificant as well?

Comment: @IceTea - The "O" in big O notation stands for "Order of Magnitude". In other words, at what _rate_ does the time increase as the number of items increases. Halving n doesn't change the _rate_ at which n is increasing. hth

Comment: @IceTea, to give you insight/intuition to your question. If you chart out `n` versus `n/2` you'll see that they both make a straight line. This puts them in the same class as they have similar growth rates (think of it as the shape of the charting). Similarly, if you charted out `log_2` versus `log_3` you'll see that they both take on "similar shapes" or "similar growth rates".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but at least based on what I've learnt so far, the correct answer to my previous question is that big O time complexities represent asymptotic time complexities, so is indeed that when n --> infinity, the constant becomes insignificant.

Comment: @IceTea, Explanation given by @Shai and @James is more accurate, `n/2 or 2n or n+2 or n` will have different-different line in the graph but they will have same growth rate which means all of them will follow a linear growth.

Comment: New here. Can anybody explain to me as why Algorithm 3 is different than Algorithm 7? They all run less than n times.

Comment: How about the case where we have two nested loops, but the second iterator depends on the first one, does this dependency affect the time complexity?

Comment: @Bionix1441 can you provide an example? e.g. is the following like what you are referring too: `for(i=0; i<n; i++){ for(j=i; j<n; j++) { print "foo";}}` if so, then yes, in this case example it would be the equivalent of a summation from 1 to n prints (think of the triangle shape it makes if you print each value line by line), which equals `(n*(n+1))/2` which is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @SuShiS, `Alg_3` is increasing by multiplication where `Alg_7` is increasing by addition. For small numbers this may not be as obvious, but look at it when you have a value that is larger (say a septillion, 10^24) it starts to help things become more clear. `Alg_7` is only half the value of n, where `Alg_3` would be more of the log of n. The larger the value for `n` you pick, the clearer it becomes. :)

Comment: This answer has been the most useful for me, could you explain why the variations like `for(int j = 0; j < n; j = j + 2)` are still the same as whatever they follow? In the example I used why is this still `O(n^2)` if the loop counter increment means there will be less iterations?

Answer (score 298):

The explanation below is using the case of a fully *balanced* binary tree to help you understand how we get logarithmic time complexity.

Binary tree is a case where a problem of size n is divided into sub-problem of size n/2 until we reach a problem of size 1:

[image: height of a binary tree]

And that's how you get O(log n) which is the amount of work that needs to be done on the above tree to reach a solution.

A common algorithm with O(log n) time complexity is Binary Search whose recursive relation is T(n/2) + O(1) i.e. at every subsequent level of the tree you divide problem into half and do constant amount of additional work.

Comment: newbie here. So could you say the tree height is the division rate by recursion to reach size n=1?

Comment: @Cody, yes for the most part your observation is accurate. This example illustrates/utilizes `log_2`. Your observation would expend beyond `log_2` and would be accurate for any `log_x` where `x > 1`. Doing straight division may not lead to 1 exactly though, so you may want to say the recursive division until the `Ceiling()` of the latest division is equal to 1, or something similar.

Answer (score 184):

If you had a function that takes:

```
1 millisecond to complete if you have 2 elements.
2 milliseconds to complete if you have 4 elements.
3 milliseconds to complete if you have 8 elements.
4 milliseconds to complete if you have 16 elements.
...
n milliseconds to complete if you have 2^n elements.
```

Then it takes log<sub>2</sub>(n) time. The [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), loosely speaking, means that the relationship only needs to be true for large n, and that constant factors and smaller terms can be ignored.

Comment: is  log2(n) the same as o(log n) ?

Comment: Yes, see comment by nawfal for another answer here: (copy-pasting) - in programming context, the base of log is 2 (not 10), so O(log n) scales like 1 sec for 10 elements, 2 sec for 20, 3 for 40 etc

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, the example in this solution illustrates `log_2`, which is in the class `O(log(n))`. There are many others in the same class of `O(log(n))` i.e. `log_x` where `x > 1`

Comment: @Andrejs, your comment `so O(log n) scales like 1 sec for 10 elements, 2 sec for 20, 3 for 40 etc` is inaccurate. That pattern/class would match/align with `O(n)` not `O(log(n))`. If someone was interested in `log_10` then an equivalent example would be 1 sec for 10 elements, 2 seconds for 100, 3 for 1000, etc.

Answer (score 152):

**The logarithm**

Ok let's try and fully understand what a logarithm actually is.

Imagine we have a rope and we have tied it to a horse. If the rope is directly tied to the horse, the force the horse would need to pull away (say, from a man) is directly 1.

Now imagine the rope is looped round a pole. The horse to get away will now have to pull many times harder. The amount of times will depend on the roughness of the rope and the size of the pole, but let's assume it will multiply one's strength by 10 (when the rope makes a complete turn).

Now if the rope is looped once, the horse will need to pull 10 times harder. If the human decides to make it really difficult for the horse, he may loop the rope again round a pole, increasing it's strength by an additional 10 times. A third loop will again increase the strength by a further 10 times.

[image]

We can see that for each loop, the value increases by 10. The number of turns required to get any number is called the logarithm of the number i.e. we need 3 posts to multiple your strength by 1000 times, 6 posts to multiply your strength by 1,000,000.

3 is the logarithm of 1,000, and 6 is the logarithm of 1,000,000 (base 10).

**So what does O(log n) actually mean?**

In our example above, our 'growth rate' is **O(log n)**. For every additional loop, the force our rope can handle is 10 times more:

```
Turns | Max Force
  0   |   1
  1   |   10
  2   |   100
  3   |   1000
  4   |   10000
  n   |   10^n
```

Now the example above did use base 10, but fortunately the base of the log is insignificant when we talk about big o notation.

Now let's imagine you are trying to guess a number between 1-100.

```
Your Friend: Guess my number between 1-100! 
Your Guess: 50
Your Friend: Lower!
Your Guess: 25
Your Friend: Lower!
Your Guess: 13
Your Friend: Higher!
Your Guess: 19
Your Friend: Higher!
Your Friend: 22
Your Guess: Lower!
Your Guess: 20
Your Friend: Higher!
Your Guess: 21
Your Friend: YOU GOT IT!
```

Now it took you 7 guesses to get this right. But what is the relationship here? What is the most amount of items that you can guess from each additional guess?

```
Guesses | Items
  1     |   2
  2     |   4
  3     |   8
  4     |   16
  5     |   32
  6     |   64
  7     |   128
  10    |   1024
```

Using the graph, we can see that if we use a binary search to guess a number between 1-100 it will take us **at most** 7 attempts. If we had 128 numbers, we could also guess the number in 7 attemps but 129 numbers will takes us **at most** 8 attempts (in relations to logarithms, here we would need 7 guesses for a 128 value range, 10 guesses for a 1024 value range. 7 is the logarithm of 128, 10 is the logarithm of 1024 (base 2)).

Notice that I have bolded 'at most'. Big-O notation always refers to the worse case. If you're lucky, you could guess the number in one attempt and so the best case is O(1), but that's another story.

> We can see that for every guess our data set is shrinking. A good rule of thumb to identify if an algorithm has a logarithmtic time is
>   to see if the data set shrinks by a certain order after each iteration

**What about O(n log n)?**

You will eventually come across a linearithmic time **O(n log(n))** algorithm. The rule of thumb above applies again, but this time the logarithmic function has to run n times e.g. reducing the size of a list **n times**, which occurs in algorithms like a mergesort.

You can easily identify if the algorithmic time is n log n. Look for an outer loop which iterates through a list (O(n)). Then look to see if there is an inner loop. If the inner loop is **cutting/reducing** the data set on each iteration, that loop is (O(log n)), and so the overall algorithm is = **O(n log n)**.

*Disclaimer: The rope-logarithm example was grabbed from the excellent [Mathematician's Delight book by W.Sawyer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematicians-Delight-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486462404).*

Comment: No.  `In our example above, our 'growth rate' is O(log n). For every additional loop, the force our rope can handle is 10 times more`, supported by a chart which shows n==number of loops and `our 'growth rate'` => 10^n, which is NOT log n.  The example can be made correct by making `n=# horses`, which requires log n loops to restrain.  Poor pedogogical examples produce students who only believe they understand.

Answer (score 114):

Logarithmic running time (`O(log n)`) essentially means that the running time grows in proportion to the *logarithm* of the input size - as an example, if 10 items takes at most some amount of time `x`, and 100 items takes at most, say, `2x`, and 10,000 items takes at most `4x`, then it's looking like an `O(log n)` time complexity.

Comment: +1, but you really should point out that it's log2, not log10.

Comment: log2 or log10 is irrelevant. They only differ by a scale factor, which makes them of the same order, i.e. they still grow at the same rate.

Comment: The fun thing about logarithms is that when comparing relative heights, the exact base you use doesn't matter. `log 10,000 / log 100` is 2 regardless of what base you use.

Comment: To be nitpicky, O(lg n) means that the runtime is *at most* proportional to lg n. What you describe is Theta(lg n).

Comment: @rgrig: That is true. I've edited in a few "at mosts" to indicate the upper-bound nature of big-O.

Comment: @rgrig he described both O and theta: Theta(lg n) implies O(lg n)

Comment: @klochner: "what is an even number?" "1+1 is an even number" "you described the number 2" "no, he described both even numbers and the number 2 because being 2 implies being even". What's your point?

Comment: @rgrig - I read your comment as applying to the example rather than the definition.  If we're nitpicking, he *defined* Theta (loosely), and *described* a function that is both O and Theta

Comment: @klochner: You win the nitpicking game :) I should have said "define".

Answer (score 71):

First I recommend you to read following book;

[Algorithms (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X)

Here is some functions and their expected complexities. Numbers are indicating **statement execution frequencies**.

[image: Here is some functions and their expected complexities]

Following **Big-O Complexity Chart** also taken from [bigocheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)
[image: Big-O Complexity Chart]

Lastly very simple showcase there is shows how it is calculated;

Anatomy of a program’s statement execution frequencies.

Analyzing the running time of a program (example).

[image: Analyzing the running time of a program]

Comment: I wouldn't put O(n log n) in the *bad* basket. It belongs to the *fair* one.

Comment: When viewing the big-O complexity chart (above) you have to remember O(n) is actual linear point, not the pink/orange boarder. @Andre That's why O(n log n) is correctly marked in 'bad' performance bracket, it is worse performance than linear.

Comment: @JavaBeast correct, while the performance of O(n log n) is technically worse than O(n), refer to the table above, which presents a good comparison of them (see the growth of the two). otoh the chart, from a different source, is contradictory because it puts O(1) and O(log n) in the same good/excellent. their relative order of growth is comparable to O(n) and O(n log n). tl;dr; O(n log n) is not excellent, but is far from bad.

Comment: I agree with @AndréWerlang here. For example Quicksort is considered as a pretty efficient sorting algorithm, and it's average complexity is O(n log n), and it definitely does not deserved to be put in bad basket.

Comment: This answer is wrong! It assumes that N = N * N. In fact N = N! Your example is actually N cubed. You do the same in your graph. Your O(n) should actually be the divide between horrible and bad. Mathematical proof: You say that for loop is constant with O(1). That's what the 1 really means, not dependent on N. It just means not variable. But it is variable as it's dependent on N. Twice N and half the time. Therefore it's invalid. If it's from that book, don't buy it! The code graphic you've shown isn't real, it's a joke, look, "Theesome", it means three people having sex at once! OMG

Comment: Shouldn't O(n) be on the diagonal?

Comment: @csguy what r you talking about?

Comment: see what @jgmjgm said (i also agree)

Comment: What's wrong with the last picture? It is pretty absolute, it shows execution frequencies. Graph is another discussion point, I took it as a rough reference. First pic, just shows single math over different algo executions. This answer is not given as an academic reference.

Comment: Please check this => https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/ThreeSum.java.html this example clearly says "A program with cubic running time." The example I gave for just a showcase for calculation.

Comment: If you make the arrows sensible it'll make it look less like the first loop is log(1) at a glance. Use a plotter instead of the chart shown there. The chart means very little. It's a distortion liable to mislead. n log n still falls into a category of bad for scaling as it gets disproportionately worse the more there is to process. O(n) means the work is proportionate to the amount of items. A subjective scale should come with some explanation. You have a table trying to show exact values (but n log n is n log 10) then you jump to an opinionated chart that's not that table.

Answer (score 63):

You can think of O(log N) intuitively by saying the time is proportional to the number of digits in N.

If an operation performs constant time work on each digit or bit of an input, the whole operation will take time proportional to the number of digits or bits in the input, not the magnitude of the input; thus, O(log N) rather than O(N).

If an operation makes a series of constant time decisions each of which halves (reduces by a factor of 3, 4, 5..) the size of the input to be considered, the whole will take time proportional to log base 2 (base 3, base 4, base 5...) of the size N of the input, rather than being O(N).

And so on.

Comment: Accurate enough and more easily grasped than most explanations, I reckon.

Comment: it's an explanation of `log<sub>10</sub> N`, is it?

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 they didn't say what base the number of digits was in. In any case though, log₂(n) = log₁₀(n)/log₁₀(2) and 1/log₁₀(2) is hence a constant multiplier, with the same principle applying to all other bases. This shows two things. Firstly that moonshadow's principle applies whatever the base (though the lower the base, the fewer "jags" in the estimate) and also that O(log n) is O(log n) no matter what base the calculation that led you to that conclusion.

Comment: "proportional" ... "each of which halves the size of the input" ??????

Answer (score 61):

> What's log<sub>b</sub>(n)?

It is the number of times you can cut a log of length n repeatedly into b equal parts before reaching a section of size 1.

Comment: Excellent Comment! It's concise and exactly the answer I am after.

Answer (score 56):

The best way I've always had to mentally visualize an algorithm that runs in O(log n) is as follows:

If you increase the problem size by a multiplicative amount (i.e. multiply its size by 10), the work is only increased by an additive amount.

Applying this to your binary tree question so you have a good application: if you double the number of nodes in a binary tree, the height only increases by 1 (an additive amount).  If you double it again, it still only increased by 1.  (Obviously I'm assuming it stays balanced and such).  That way, instead of doubling your work when the problem size is multiplied, you're only doing very slightly more work. That's why O(log n) algorithms are awesome.

Comment: Since 2^x is the inverse of log, then would the following be true? If you increase the problem size by [an additive amount], then the work is increased by a multiplicative amount.

Answer (score 25):

Divide and conquer algorithms usually have a `logn` component to the running time. This comes from the repeated halving of the input.

In the case of binary search, every iteration you throw away half of the input. It should be noted that in Big-O notation, log is log base 2.

Edit: As noted, the log base doesn't matter, but when deriving the Big-O performance of an algorithm, the log factor will come from halving, hence why I think of it as base 2.

Comment: Why is it log base 2? In randomized quicksort for example, I don't think it is base 2. As far as i know, the base doesn't matter, as log base a (n) = log2 (n) / log2 (a), so every logarithm is different from another by a constant, and constants are ignored in big-o notation. In fact, writing the base of a log in big-o notation is a mistake in my opinion, as you are writing a constant.

Comment: Re "log is log base 2": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569702/is-big-ologn-log-base-e/1569710#1569710

Comment: Very true that it can be converted to any base and it does not matter, but if you are trying to derive the Big-O performance and you see constant halving, it helps to understand that you wont see log base 10 reflected in the code.

Comment: An aside: In things such as B-trees, where nodes have a fan-out of more than 2 (i.e. "wider" than a binary tree), you'll still see O(logn) growth,  because it's still divide-and-conquer, but the base of the log will be related to the fan-out.

Comment: The digression on log 2 was quite helpful, actually.

Comment: If we use lg for base 2 and log for base 10. Then lg N = log N / log 2. Notice that 1/log2 is a constant. Therefore O(log N) = O(lg N)

Answer (score 17):

O(log n) is a bit misleading, more precisely it's O(log<sub>2</sub> n), i.e. (logarithm with base 2).

The height of a balanced binary tree is O(log<sub>2</sub> n), since every node has two (note the "two" as in log<sub>2</sub> n) child nodes. So, a tree with n nodes has a height of log<sub>2</sub> n.

Another example is binary search, which has a running time of O(log<sub>2</sub> n) because at every step you divide the search space by 2.

Comment: O(log n) is the same order as O(ld n) or O(LN n). They are proportional. I understand that for learning purposes it's easier to use ld.

Comment: "more precisely it's O(ld n)" - No, it isn't: all logs are the same order (each differing from the others only by some constant scaling factor, which is ignored/ignorable).

Comment: you're right chris, very bad wording. should have said it as helios did. it helps for learning/understanding but finally all logs are the same order.

Answer (score 16):

> But what exactly is O(log n)? For example, what does it mean to say that the height of a >complete binary tree is O(log n)?

I would rephrase this as 'height of a complete binary tree is log n'.  Figuring the height of a complete binary tree would be O(log n), if you were traversing down step by step.

> I cannot understand how to identify a function with a logarithmic
>   time.

Logarithm is essentially the inverse of exponentiation.  So, if each 'step' of your function is eliminating a **factor** of elements from the original item set, that is a logarithmic time algorithm.

For the tree example, you can easily see that stepping down a level of nodes cuts down an exponential number of elements as you continue traversing. The popular example of looking through a name-sorted phone book is essentially equivalent to traversing down a binary search tree (middle page is the root element, and you can deduce at each step whether to go left or right).

Comment: +1 for mentioning "Logarithm is essentially the inverse of exponentiation".

Answer (score 13):

`O(log n)` refers to a function (or algorithm, or step in an algorithm) working in an amount of time proportional to the logarithm (usually base 2 in most cases, but not always, and in any event this is insignificant by big-O notation*) of the size of the input.

The logarithmic function is the inverse of the exponential function. Put another way, if your input grows exponentially (rather than linearly, as you would normally consider it), your function grows linearly.

`O(log n)` running times are very common in any sort of divide-and-conquer application, because you are (ideally) cutting the work in half every time. If in each of the division or conquer steps, you are doing constant time work (or work that is not constant-time, but with time growing more slowly than `O(log n)`), then your entire function is `O(log n)`. It's fairly common to have each step require linear time on the input instead; this will amount to a total time complexity of `O(n log n)`.

The running time complexity of binary search is an example of `O(log n)`. This is because in binary search, you are always ignoring half of your input in each later step by dividing the array in half and only focusing on one half with each step. Each step is constant-time, because in binary search you only need to compare one element with your key in order to figure out what to do next irregardless of how big the array you are considering is at any point. So you do approximately log(n)/log(2) steps.

The running time complexity of merge sort is an example of `O(n log n)`. This is because you are dividing the array in half with each step, resulting in a total of approximately log(n)/log(2) steps. However, in each step you need to perform merge operations on all elements (whether it's one merge operation on two sublists of n/2 elements, or two merge operations on four sublists of n/4 elements, is irrelevant because it adds to having to do this for n elements in each step). Thus, the total complexity is `O(n log n)`.

*Remember that big-O notation, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), constants don't matter. Also by the [change of base rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_base_formula_for_logs#Changing_the_base) for logarithms, the only difference between logarithms of different bases is a constant factor.

Comment: The final * note solved my confusion about logarithms being based on 2 or 10 :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

These 2 cases will  take O(log n) time

```
case 1: f(int n) {
      int i;
      for (i = 1; i < n; i=i*2)
        printf("%d", i);
    }


 case 2  : f(int n) {
      int i;
      for (i = n; i>=1 ; i=i/2)
        printf("%d", i);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but wouldn't i always be zero and the loops run forever in both of those cases, since 0*2=0 and 0/2=0?

Comment: @dj_segfault, that was my mistake.I think now it does make sense..:)

Comment: @RaviBisla Other answers state that an input of 10 would take 1 time as much as 10 loops, and an input of 100 would take 3 times the input time of 1, thats definetly not the case with those examples. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307330/1667868

Answer (score 11):

It simply means that the time needed for this task grows with log(n) (example : 2s for n = 10, 4s for n = 100, ...). Read the Wikipedia articles on [Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more precisions.

Answer (score 10):

Simply put: At each step of your algorithm you can cut the work in half. (Asymptotically equivalent to third, fourth, ...)

Comment: This answer is very imprecise. First of all, you can think of cutting the work in half only in the case of the logarithm in base 2. It's really incredible how this answer (and most of the answers to the original question) received so many up-votes. "(Asymptotically equivalent to third, fourth, ...)"? Why answering a question if you don't have time?

Answer (score 8):

If you plot a logarithmic function on a graphical calculator or something similar, you'll see that it rises really slowly -- even more slowly than a linear function.

This is why algorithms with a logarithmic time complexity are highly sought after: even for really big n (let's say n = 10^8, for example), they perform more than acceptably.

Answer (score 7):

I can add something interesting, that I read in book by Kormen and etc. a long time ago. Now, imagine a problem, where we have to find a solution in a problem space. This problem space should be finite.

Now, if you can prove, that at every iteration of your algorithm you cut off a fraction of this space, that is no less than some limit, this means that your algorithm is running in O(logN) time.

I should point out, that we are talking here about a relative fraction limit, not the absolute one. The binary search is a classical example. At each step we throw away 1/2 of the problem space. But binary search is not the only such example. Suppose, you proved somehow, that at each step you throw away at least 1/128 of problem space. That means, your program is still running at O(logN) time, although significantly slower than the binary search. This is a very good hint in analyzing of recursive algorithms. It often can be proved that at each step the recursion will not use several variants, and this leads to the cutoff of some fraction in problem space.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, if you have a list of n elements, and create a binary tree from that list (like in the divide and conquer algorithm), you will keep dividing by 2 until you reach lists of size 1 (the leaves).

At the first step, you divide by 2. You then have 2 lists (2^1), you divide each by 2, so you have 4 lists (2^2), you divide again, you have 8 lists (2^3)and so on until your list size is 1

That gives you the equation :

**`n/(2^steps)=1 <=> n=2^steps <=> lg(n)=steps`**

(you take the lg of each side, lg being the log base 2)

Comment: Until some malware begins to insert a new list with x length at two levels before the leaves nodes. Then it will seem to be an infinite loop...

Comment: I didn't get your comment. Is my explanation wrong ?

Comment: I was only making a hypothetical joke. I wasn't really meaning anything by it.

Answer (score 6):

The complete binary example is O(ln n) because the search looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Searching for 4 yields 3 hits: 6, 3 then 4. And log2 12 = 3, which is a good apporximate to how many hits where needed.

Comment: thanks for the example. It clearly says how our algorithm can use logarithmic time in divide and conquer method.

Comment: So if its a loop of n/2 its always log(n)?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Tree]

`log x to base b = y` is the inverse of `b^y = x`

If you have an M-ary tree of depth d and size n, then:

- traversing the whole tree ~ O(M^d) = O(n)
- Walking a single path in the tree ~ O(d) = O(log n to base M)

Answer (score 6):

I can give an example for a for loop and maybe once grasped the concept maybe it will be simpler to understand in different contexts.

That means that in the loop the step grows exponentially. E.g.

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i=i*2) {;}
```

The complexity in O-notation of this program is O(log(n)). Let's try to loop through it by hand (n being somewhere between 512 and 1023 (excluding 1024):

```
step: 1   2   3   4   5    6    7    8     9     10
   i: 1   2   4   8   16   32   64   128   256   512
```

Although n is somewhere between 512 and 1023, only 10 iterations take place. This is because the step in the loop grows exponentially and thus takes only 10 iterations to reach the termination.

> The logarithm of x (to the base of a) is the reverse function of a^x.
>
> It is like saying that logarithm is the inverse of exponential.

Now try to see it that way, if exponential grows very fast then logarithm grows (inversely) very slow.

The difference between O(n) and O(log(n)) is huge, similar to the difference between O(n) and O(a^n) (a being a constant).

Answer (score 6):

Every time we write an algorithm or code we try to analyze its asymptotic complexity.
It is different from its **time complexity**.

Asymptotic complexity is the behavior of execution time of an algorithm while the time complexity is the actual execution time. But some people use these terms interchangeably.

Because time complexity depends on various parameters viz.
         1. Physical System
         2. Programming Language
         3. coding Style
         4. And much more ......

**The actual execution time is not a good measure for analysis.**

Instead we take input size as the parameter because whatever the code is, the input is same.
**So the execution time is a function of input size.**

Following is an example of Linear Time Algorithm

**Linear Search**
 
Given n input elements, to search an element in the array you need **at most 'n' comparisons**. In other words, no matter what programming language you use, what coding style you prefer, on what system you execute it. In the worst case scenario it requires only n comparisons.The execution time is linearly proportional to the input size.

And its not just search, whatever may be the work (increment, compare or any operation) its a function of input size.

So when you say any algorithm is O(log n)
it means the execution time is log times the input size n.

As the input size increases the work done(here the execution time) increases.(Hence proportionality)

```
      n      Work
      2     1 units of work
      4     2 units of work
      8     3 units of work
```

See as the input size increased the work done is increased and it is independent of any machine.
And if you try to find out the value of units of work 
It's actually dependent onto those above specified parameters.It will change according to the systems and all.

Comment: "time complexity" does not mean "actual execution time". This answer is simply wrong.

Answer (score 5):

In information technology it means that:

```
  f(n)=O(g(n)) If there is suitable constant C and N0 independent on N, 
  such that
  for all N>N0  "C*g(n) > f(n) > 0" is true.
```

Ant it seems that this notation was mostly have taken from mathematics.

In this article there is a quote:
[D.E. Knuth, "BIG OMICRON AND BIG OMEGA AND BIG THETA", 1976](http://www.phil.uu.nl/datastructuren/09-10/knuth_big_omicron.pdf):

> On the basis of the issues discussed here, I propose that members of
>   SIGACT, and editors of computer science and mathematics journals,
>   adopt notations as defined above, unless **a better alternative can be
>   found reasonably soon**.

Today is 2016, but we use it still today.

---

In mathematical analysis it means that:

```
  lim (f(n)/g(n))=Constant; where n goes to +infinity
```

But even in mathematical analysis sometimes this symbol was used in meaning "C*g(n) > f(n) > 0".

As I know from university the symbol was intoduced by German mathematician Landau (1877-1938)

Answer (score 5):

O(logn) is one of the polynomial time complexity to measure the runtime performance of any code.

I hope you have already heard of Binary search algorithm.

Let's assume you have to find an element in the array of size N.

Basically, the code execution is like
N
N/2
N/4
N/8....etc

If you sum all the work done at each level you will end up with n(1+1/2+1/4....) and that is equal to O(logn)

Comment: How on earth `log(n)` equals `n`?!

Comment: This is totally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a intuition based answer I would like to put up two interpretations for you.

1. Imagine a very high hill with a very broad base as well. To reach the top of the hill there are two ways: one is a dedicated pathway going spirally around the hill reaching at the top, the other: small terrace like carvings cut out to provide a staircase. Now if the first way is reaching in linear time O(n), the second one is O(log n).
2. Imagine an algorithm, which accepts an integer, `n` as input and completes in time proportional to `n` then it is O(n) or theta(n) but if it runs in time proportion to the `number of digits or the number of bits in the binary representation on number` then the algorithm runs in O(log n) or theta(log n) time.

Comment: please edit. has "O(n) or theta(n)" in both scenarios...? Also, I've heard this a lot, the size vs the # digits. Are we saying size === 128 for n=10000000 and digits === 8 for n=10000000? Please elucidate.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithms in the Divide and Conquer paradigm are of complexity O(logn). One example here, calculate your own power function,

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    int temp;
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    temp = power(x, y/2);
    if (y%2 == 0)
        return temp*temp;
    else
        return x*temp*temp;
}
```

from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that the height of the tree is the length of the longest path from the root to a leaf, and that the height of a node is the length of the longest path from that node to a leaf. The path means the number of nodes we encounter while traversing the tree between two nodes. In order to achieve O(log n) time complexity, the tree should be balanced, meaning that the difference of the height between the children of any node should be less than or equal to 1. Therefore, trees do not always guarantee a time complexity O(log n), unless they are balanced. Actually in some cases, the time complexity of searching in a tree can be O(n) in the worst case scenario.

You can take a look at the balance trees such as `AVL tree`. This one works on balancing the tree while inserting data in order to keep a time complexity of (log n) while searching in the tree.

Answer (score -5):

Big O notations
For reference. this may help !

**Big O---------------**     **Sorting--------------** **Complexity**

```
O(log N)     -Binary search      - logarithmic

O(N)         -Simple search      - Linear

O(N*log N)   -Quicksort          - loglinear 

O(2^N)       -recursive          - Exponential

O(N2)        -Selection sort     - directly proportional to the square of the input size.
```