# Example of a O(2^N) algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been told that

> O(2^N) denotes an algorithm whose growth will double with each additional element in the input data set

Can someone provide an example that behaves like this?

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: It's not an algorythm. This is Big O notation for rating algorythm complextity

Comment: It's clear that he's trying to understand the concept of `O(2^n)`, and what that may look like in practice.

Comment: Even after providing clear explanation, not answering and voting it for negative and voting it for "close the question" is not fair

Comment: if i metion "waht or how" then only it will be considered as good question, its funny comment. Also i clarifed "can anyone help in this algorithm". Please read the question properly

Comment: @Damodar: I've taken a crack at making your question agree with the answer that you accepted. I hope that this is what you meant, but I don't actually *know*. That uncertainty is probably the source of the negative reaction you received: despite Travis' feelings on the matter I found your question very unclear. Presumably the closers were in a similar position.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recursive computation of Fibonacci numbers is a good example of O(2<sup>N</sup>) algorithm (though [O(2<sup>N</sup>) is not a tight bound for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360748/computational-complexity-of-fibonacci-sequence)):

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make difference between O(2^n) and O(log n) ?

Comment: check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly