# What does Logn actually mean?

Tags: algorithm, performance, complexity-theory, quicksort, logarithm

I am just studying for my class in Algorithms and have been looking over QuickSort. I understand the algorithm and how it works, but not how to get the number of comparisons it does, or what logn actually means, at the end of the day.

I understand the basics, to the extent of :

```
x=logb(Y) then
b^x = Y
```

But what does this mean in terms of algorithm performance? It's the number of comparisons you need to do, I understand that...the whole idea just seems so unintelligible though. Like, for QuickSort, each level K invocation involves `2^k` invocations each involving sublists of length `n/2^K.`

So, summing to find the number of comparisons :

```
log n
Σ 2^k. 2(n/2^k) = 2n(1+logn)
k=0
```

Why are we summing up to log n ? Where did 2n(1+logn) come from? Sorry for the vagueness of my descriptions, I am just so confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does O(log n) mean exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)

Answer (score 4):

If you consider a full, balanced binary tree, then layer by layer you have 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... vertices.  If the total number of vertices in the tree is 2^n - 1 then you have 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^(n-1) vertices, counting layer by layer.  Now, let N = 2^n (the size of the tree), then the height of the tree is n, and n = log2(N) (the height of the tree).  That's what the log(n) means in these Big O expressions.

Answer (score 1):

below is a sample tree:

```
      1
    /   \ 
   2     3
  / \   / \
 4   5 6   7
```

number of nodes in tree is 7 but high of tree is log 7 = 3, log comes when you have divide and conquer methods, in quick sort you divide list into 2 sublist, and continue this until rich small lists, divisions takes `logn` time (in average case), because the high of division is `log n`, partitioning in each level takes O(n), because in each level in average you partition N numbers, (may be there are too many list for partitioning, but average number of numbers is N in each level, in fact some of count of lists is N). So for simple observation if you have balanced partition tree you have `log n` time for partitioning, which means high of tree.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 forget about b-trees for sec

here' math :  log2 N = k is same 2^k=N .. its the definion of log
, it could be natural log(e) N = k aka e^k = n,, or decimal log10 N = k is 10^k = n

## 2 see perfect , balanced tree

1
1+ 1
1 + 1 + 1+ 1
8 ones
16 ones
etc

how many elements? 1+2+4+8..etc , so for 2 level b-tree there are 2^2-1 elements, for 3 level tree 2^3-1 and etc.. SO HERE'S MAGIC FORMULA: N_TREE_ELEMENTS=  number OF levels^ 2 -1 ,or using definition of log :  log2 number OF levels=  number_of_tree_elements (Can forget about -1 )

## 3 lets say there's a task to find element in N elements b-tree, w/  K levels (aka height)

where how b-tree is constructed log2 height =  number_of_tree elements

MOST IMPORTANT

so by how b-tree is constructed you need no more then 'height' OPERATIONS to find element in all N elements , or less.. so WHAT IS HEIGHT equals : log2 number_of_tree_elements..

so you need log2 N_number_of_tree_elements.. or log(N) for shorter

Answer (score 0):

To understand what O(log(n)) means you might wanna read up on [Big O notaion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In shot it means, that if your data set gets 1024 times bigger you runtime will only be 10 times longer (or less)(for base 2).

MergeSort runs in O(n*log(n)), which means it will take 10 240 times longer. [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) runs in O(n^2), which means it will take 1024^2 = 1 048 576 times longer. So there are really some time to safe :)

---

To understand your sum, you must look at the mergesort algorithm as a tree:

```
         sort(3,1,2,4)
        /            \
   sort(3,1)      sort(2,4)
    /     \        /     \
sort(3) sort(1) sort(2) sort(4)
```

The sum iterates over each level of the tree. k=0 it the top, k= log(n) is the buttom. The tree will always be of height log2(n) (as it a balanced [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)).

To do a little math:

```
Σ 2^k * 2(n/2^k) = 
2 * Σ 2^k * (n/2^k) =
2 * Σ n*2^k/2^k = 
2 * Σ n = 
2 * n * (1+log(n)) //As there are log(n)+1 steps from 0 to log(n) inclusive
```

---

This is of course a lot of work to do, especially if you have more complex algoritms. In those situations you get really happy for the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), but for the moment it might just get you more confused. It's very theoretical so don't worry if you don't understand it right away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, to understand issues like this, [this is a good way to think about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it/630142#630142).