# Is there a way to tell whether a subroutine has runtime log(n)?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Usually the rule is that if there is a loop of 1 to n elements then the complexity is O(n), and further nested loops are n x O(n). However, when do we say if a subroutine has complexity O(log n)?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16785817/2128327

Comment: No need to downvote my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in each iteration we reduce the problem size be a factor of X , we can say that the problem is `O(log n)`

***E.g - Binary Search:*** in each iteration we reduce the problem size by factor of 2

Answer (score 1):

You can take as first example binary search. A explanation of the complexity of this algorithm can be taken from a related question [how to calculate binary search complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185079/how-to-calculate-binary-serch-complexity). It shown that the calculation of this type of complexity can be obtain from the recurrence.