# Octave containers.Map() undefined

Tags: octave

I need to use `containers.Map()` to convert some MATLAB code to Octave. I see in the GNU Octave bug tracker #49559 that `containers.Map()` has been implemented, but I am still getting `error: 'containers' undefined` when I try to use it. Is this functionality available in the current release builds, and if so how should I access it?

Comment: Could you please provide a code example on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't think `containers.Map()` has been pushed to the release version, so you'll have to either build from the development source or wait for a new release. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622084/converting-matlab-to-octave-is-there-a-containers-map-equivalent) may be useful in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks @excaza. This isn't time critical so I will monitor releases to see when it becomes available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the new functionality is written [as .m file](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/b04466113212/scripts/%2Bcontainers/Map.m) you can just download the file and insert it into your existing 4.2.x installation.

You are not mentioning if you are using GNU Octave on GNU/Linux or windoze so I assume GNU/Linux here:

- create a directory "+containers" in Octaves "m" folder (you have to use sudo if it's a global install)
- wget http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/b04466113212/scripts/%2Bcontainers/Map.m

voilá, Map in OCtave 4.2.1:

```
octave:1> ver
GNU Octave Version: 4.2.1
...
octave:2> containers.Map
ans =

  containers.Map object with properties:

    Count     : 0
    KeyType   : char
    ValueType : any
```