# Proof that the height of a balanced binary-search tree is log(n)

Tags: performance, tree, binary-search-tree

The binary-search algorithm takes log(n) time, because of the fact that the height of the tree (with n nodes) would be log(n).

How would you prove this?

Comment: visual answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/550393

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Now here I am not giving mathematical proof. Try to understand the problem using log to the base 2. Log<sub>2</sub> is the normal meaning of log in computer science.

First, understand it is binary logarithm (log<sub>2</sub>n) (logarithm to the base 2).
For example,

- the binary logarithm of 1 is 0
- the binary logarithm of 2 is 1
- the binary logarithm of 3 is 1
- the binary logarithm of 4 is 2
- the binary logarithm of 5, 6, 7 is 2
- the binary logarithm of 8-15 is 3
- the binary logarithm of 16-31 is 4 and so on.

For each height the number of nodes in a fully balanced tree are

```
    Height  Nodes  Log calculation
      0        1      log21 = 0
      1        3      log23 = 1
      2        7      log27 = 2
      3       15      log215 = 3
```

Consider a balanced tree with between 8 and 15 nodes (any number, let's say 10). It is always going to be height 3 because log<sub>2</sub> of any number from 8 to 15 is 3.

In a balanced binary tree the size of the problem to be solved is halved with every iteration. Thus roughly log<sub>2</sub>n iterations are needed to obtain a problem of size 1.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Let's assume at first that the tree is complete - it has 2^N leaf nodes. We try to prove that you need N recursive steps for a binary search.

With each recursion step you cut the number of candidate leaf nodes exactly by half (because our tree is complete). This means that after N halving operations there is exactly one candidate node left.

As each recursion step in our binary search algorithm corresponds to exactly one height level the height is exactly N.

Generalization to all balanced binary trees: If the tree has less nodes than 2^N we for sure don't need *more* halvings. We might need less or the same amount but never more.

Comment: A complete tree just means that every level is full except possibly the lowest level, which must be filled from left to right. I know that a leaf node is just a node without children. How would you know that a complete tree has 2^N. An empty tree is technically a complete tree. An empty tree has a height of 0, meaning from that equation ,an empty tree will have 2^0 or 1 leaf nodes. But by the definition of an empty tree, the tree will have no nodes. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'd prove by induction that a complete binary tree of N levels has 2^N leaf nodes. The insight is that adding another level attaches 2 nodes to every existing leaf node and therefore doubles the number of new leafs. You can resolve the concern about empty trees by adding a special case about empty trees to the proof or by exluding this case from the proof obligation.

Comment: Do you mean a complete and perfectly balanced binary search tree? Cause a binary search tree, with in order traversal (0,1,empty) is complete because it is filled at every level except the last, which is filled from top to right but it only has one leaf node, which wouldn't agree to your 2^N formula

Comment: Imagine a tree that only holds data at the leaf nodes. In that case the 2^N formula holds. If we place data in the interior nodes the 2^N formula is off by at most a factor of 2 which is irrelevant to the asymptotic O(log N) behavior. The total number of nodes grows as 1+2+4+8+... which is (2^(N-1)-1). This proof is a little hand wavy but it's easy to understand and see that the O(log N) property holds.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that we have a complete tree to work with, we can say that at depth k, there are 2<sup>k</sup> nodes. You can prove this using simple induction, based on the intuition that adding an extra level to the tree will increase the number of nodes in the entire tree by the number of nodes that were in the previous level times two.

The height k of the tree is log(N), where N is the number of nodes. This can be stated as

> log<sub>2</sub>(N) = k,

and it is equivalent to

> N = 2<sup>k</sup>

To understand this, here's an example:

> 16 = 2<sup>4</sup> => log<sub>2</sub>(16) = 4

The height of the tree and the number of nodes are related *exponentially*. Taking the log of the number of nodes just allows you to work backwards to find the height.

Comment: you mean a full tree?

Comment: the answer is completely wrong. if `log2(N) = k` then for `N  = 1` we have `k = 0`, but `k` is 1, not 0 in this case

Comment: @some1here: If a binary tree has only one node, the height is considered to be 0, so OP's answer is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the height of a balanced binary tree equal to ceil(log<sub>2</sub>N) for N nodes?

> w = width of base (maximum number of leaves)

> h = height of tree (maximum number of edges from root to leaf)

> Divide w by 2 (h times) to get to 1, which counts the single root node at top.

> N = w + w/2 + ... + 1

> N = 2<sup>h</sup> + ... + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>

> = (1-2<sup>h+1</sup>) / (1-2) = 2<sup>h+1</sup>-1

> log<sub>2</sub>(N+1) = h+1

Check: if N=1, h=0.  If h=1, N=3.

This formula is for if the bottom level is full.  N will not always be so great, but would still have the same height, h.  So we must take the log's ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

Just look up the rigorous proof in Knuth, Volume 3 - Searching and Sorting Algorithms ... He does it far more rigorously than anyone else I can think of.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming

You can find it in any good Computer Science library and on the bookshelves of many (very) old geeks.

Comment: Thanks for this! For reference, this is Theorem A on Page 453 (Chapter 6.2.3 Balanced Trees).

The theorem states that the height of a balanced tree (AVL tree) with n internal nodes is bounded below by log_2 (n + 1) and bounded above by 1.4404 log_2 (n + 2) - 0.328.

Answer (score 0):

the height of a **complete binary tree** is log2(n + 1) - 1

| depth | width(number of nodes in a depth) | arithmetic to calculate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2^0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2^1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2^2 |
| 3 | 8 | 2^3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| d | 2^d | 2^d |

size of a tree(number of nodes in a tree) = `2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + 2^d = 2^(d+1) - 1`

if size of a tree is equal to n, `2^(d+1) - 1 = n`, then `d = log2(n + 1) - 1`

NOTE: This formula only works in complete binary tree

> Complete Binary Tree:
>
> All levels of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are fully filled.
> If the last level of the tree is not complete, the nodes of that level are filled from left to right