# Binary tree complexities

Tags: algorithm, search

I would like to know some complexities of binary search tree.

I can't find complete information. I want to know complexities for the following operations on a binary search tree

1. to add/insert an element
2. to remove an element
3. to find an element (as I know this one is `O(log(n))` )

Comment: it depends on your algorithm, it has not much to do with the data structure.

Comment: Binary trees in general? Or binary search trees? Or some specific self-balancing BST?

Comment: Everything about [Binary Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) in Wiki.

Comment: Yes I mean binary search tree, I just edited my question.

Comment: easy explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/550393

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insertion, deletion and searching in a binary search tree are:

- `O(N)` in the worst case;
- `O(log(N))` in the average case.

Answer (score 7):

If you have balanced binary tree, all three complexities will be of `O(log(N))`. If you are not balancing the tree, it could be `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Search is effective. But unbalanced structure (which is often the case) can lead to O(N) for search/insert/remove operations. That is why binary heap or other kind of balanced trees are preferred with O(log n).
.