# Big-O Notation and coding

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I'm struggling to wrap my head around working out big-o notation from code.

I understand the basic steps i.e.

`for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` would be **O(n)**

And that

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

would be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

I am struggling to understand where or how to calculate the logarithmic values.

i.e.

Would :

`for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i++)` be **O(log n)** or **O(n log n)** or **O(log 2n)** etc

Can someone please demonstrate in code form as to an example and how the notation was formed.

I have researched and keep getting examples where sorting is concerned and the lists are chopped etc, which makes sense in a form but I don't seem to get how to apply that to code as above.

I am new to the whole coding and big-o notation.

I have am familiar with objects, classes, loops, functions, structs, etc.
I am busy learning c++ as it is part of my course.
My text book does not explain logarithmic big-o calculations very well or pretty much at all.

Comment: Your question will probably get a better answer on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: It's `O(n)`, since you make `2n` steps.

Comment: logarithm appears when you start dividing the interval, e.g. dichotomy search; when you work with balanced trees (prune left or right brunches) etc

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly?rq=1) can be really helpful.  It's a good start at least.

Comment: Check [*"What does O(log n) mean exactly?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2307283/2432317)

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2485710 cstheory is for _research level_ questions. [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be better.

Answer (score 1):

One could represent the code as a recurrence relation:

`T(n) = T(n-1)  + 2 * c, where c = the inner part of the code`,

which we will do `2 * n` times.

Giving us solution like:
`T(n) = 2 c n + c_1, where c_1 a constant`

And since `2 * c` is a constant, and the second term, also a constant drops off, we can write:

`O(n)`

Comment: Hello, please add some formatting to the code so it is easier to read/understand. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.