# Big O Complexity in Binary Search Tree(BST)

Tags: data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree

i've been reviewing all the stuff i've learned, and found out that this [website](http://bigocheatsheet.com/), and it is saying the worst case of searching in Binary Tree has O(n) complexity. So far i've known, in Binary search tree is a sorted tree that we can search with binary search which has O(log n)-log base 2 probably.

Could anyone explain?

Comment: Linear search results in a worst case of `O(n)`. Binary search is `O(log n)`

Comment: Did you read the linked Wikipedia page?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: It's only worst case `O(log n)` if the tree is balanced.

Comment: @mattm when we begin search from root node, isn't it always going to be a binary search?

Comment: No, it isn't. It depends on the order that the elements were added to the tree.

Comment: complexity of balanced binary tree: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13093274/550393

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the absolute worst case, a binary tree with `N` elements would be like a linked list.
Hence, there would be `N` levels, and a search would take `N` traversals.

```
                                    ~ Root ~
                                      ____
                                     | 42 |
                                     |____|
                                    /      \
                               ____/        \
                              | 13 |         X
                              |____|
                             /      \
                        ____/        \
                       | 11 |         X
                       |____|
                      /      \
                     /        \
                  ...          X
```

That's why it's `O(N)` in the worst case.
And this is why we need to balance the trees to achieve `O(log N)` search.

Comment: @man.theobsolete You'll get this tree if you insert in the order `42, 13, 11`. You'll get a balanced tree if you insert `13, 11, 42`.

Answer (score 2):

O(log n) is valid only if btree is balanced.
In case of your insertions are all on the same side of the tree, to find something you must traverse all the items, then O(n)