# Time Complexity of BST

Tags: performance, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

so I know that operation on a BST operate in log time because of the halving of the structure, I was wondering what the time complexity would be if you search for a value that was not in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average case time complexity will be O(log n) and the worst case would be O(n). To understand the O(log n) complexity you can refer [What does O(log n) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)

This image will explain you how part:

[image]

I will also recommend to go through the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Performance) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It will still be O(log n). Think this way, it will search by continuously halving till it cannot locate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would it know whether the value is greater or less than the root to know what side to start looking in? I was under the impression that it would do one side then do the next and realize it isn't there

Comment: You're talking about a BST. A BST would be arranged in the following manner

`leftChild < root < rightChild`

Now, if you think about it your element would be first comparing itself with the root of the tree and then decide whether to go with the leftChild or the rightChild