# What is the time complexity for below code of the nested for loop?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

```
for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++) {
    for(j=1;j<= n/2;j++) {
        for(k=1;k<=n;k=k*2) {
            statement;
        }
    }
}
```

what is the  complexity for that code i think it would be in log with n^2 but i can't find it please answer me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=n/2;i<=n;i++) {         // it is O(n)
    for(j=1;j<= n/2;j++) {    // it is O(n)
        for(k=1;k<=n;k=k*2) { // it is O(log n)
            statement;
        }
    }
}
```

so O(n^2 * (log n))

Comment: i didn't understand how log n comes?can you explain it?

Comment: Long answer you can find, for instance, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly?rq=1
Briefly, here the complexity is log2 n. So if n grows 8 times, you need (log2 8) more time (only in the last loop), i.e. computation takes 3 times more.