# Is Time complexity O(N) or O(Log N)?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

```
i = 1;
while(i<N) {
   i*=2;
}
```

I think the time complexity of the above code is O(N) but i'm not sure about it. Can you please let me know if you think its O(Log N) and the reason?

Comment: You should see this for more correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076176/time-complexity-and-integer-inputs/48076437#48076437

Answer (score 5):

Time complexity si proportional to number of cycles. And number of cycles is exactly equal to `Log(N)/Log(2)`, where Log is any logarithm. Or just `Log2(N)`, where Log2 is logarithm with base 2. It is therefore O(Log N).

Comment: This answer is only partially correct as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076176/time-complexity-and-integer-inputs/48076437#48076437

Answer (score 3):

example: N = 10
while loop runs 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 (5 times)

if you double N, N = 20 you would expect the time complexity to also double if it were O(N).
however, that loop runs 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 (6 times)

and again, N = 40, that loop runs 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 (7 times)

This is O(log N) since the time complexity decreases as N becomes larger.

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity of i*=2 or i/=2 will be the same and it will be log2(n).

Comment: Can you please add more explanation about why it is log2(n). It will help to improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Misread i*=2 as i+=2.

It's just O(N), more precisely it would be O(N/2).

Why would you think that this would be O(log N)?

Comment: Because for the following code its O(log N):

for(int i=1;i<n;i*=2)

Comment: O(log(n)) - Logarithmic Examples:

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i = i * 2)
  print "hello";


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly