# Logarithmic Time Complexity

Tags: java, time

For this algorithm, would the Time Complexity or Big O of N be `O(n)`, `O(log n)` or something else?

Code here:

```
int i = 1;

while(i*i <= n){

    System.out.println(i);
    i += 2;

}
```

Comment: The loop iterates approximately sqrt(n) / 2 times, therefore its complexity is O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Please look into examples provided in [What does O(log n) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)
 and on wiki page [Linear_time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time). There is good explanation how to count complexity. 
According to it your algorithm complexity would be O(n), because you have one loop, which depends on provided 'n' variable.

Comment: But the number of times this algorithm runs is also based on i*I being less than or equal to n, and i increases by 2 each time.