# Skyline's algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am reading about skyline algorithm that computes the skyline in time O(nlogn) using heap. I am reading it from the following site:

http://www.zrzahid.com/the-skyline-problem/

I can see there are total 2n events, one event each for n left ends of the buildings and one event each for n right ends of the building like this website says:

http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_105

But how do we get log n? I don't have a computer science background therefore, would really like someone to break it down for me.

Comment: Because one has to *sort*, and sorting can be done as fast as *O(n log n)*.

Comment: Related: [What does O(log n) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2307283)

Comment: Thank you. This post helped me a lot.