# O(log n) clarification

Tags: performance, time-complexity, big-o

There are plenty of questions around `O(log n)` and what it actually means, not trying to open that up again.

However on this particular answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877205/10894153, this image makes no sense to me:

[image]

That being said, seeing as that answer has over 100 up votes votes and has been up for more than 2 years and no comments to indicate anything might be wrong, I assume I am misunderstanding something, hence asking here for clarification (and I can't post comments because of low reputation).

Mainly, I don't understand why `O(log(n))` is `10` when `n == 1024`. Shouldn't this be `32`, seeing as `32^2 = 1024`?

Clearly this has an effect on `O(n * log(n))` as well, but just need to understand why `O(log(1024)) = 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is correct, except that the headings could be misleading because the values below them correspond to the expressions inside the big-O, rather than to the big-O themselves. But that is understandable because O-notations have the meaning of disregarding multiplicative constants.

Something similar happens with `log(n)`. The `log` notation has also the meaning of disregarding the *base* of the logarithmic function. But that's fine in this context because:

```
log_b(n) = log_2(n)/log_2(b)                 ; see below why this is true
```

meaning that the function `log_b()` is *just a multiplicative constant away*, namely `1/log_2(b)`, from `log_2()`.

And since the table is purposely emphasizing the fact that the big-O notation disregards multiplicative constants, it is fine to assume that all logs in it are `2`-based.

In particular, `O(log(1024))` can be interpreted as `log_2(1024)` which is nothing but `10` (because `2^10 = 1024`).

---

To verify the equation above, we need to check that

```
log_2(n) = log_2(b)log_b(n)
```

By the definition of `log` we have to see that `n` is `2` to the righ-hand-side, i.e.,

```
n = 2^{log_2(b)log_b(n)}
```

but the right hand side is

```
{2^{log_2(b)}}^{log_b(n)} = b^{log_b(n)} = n
```

again by definition (applied twice).