# Why Andrew's Monotone Algorithm takes O(N LogN) times?

Tags: c#, algorithm, convex-hull

Andrew's monotone chain convex hull algorithm constructs the convex hull of a set of 2-dimensional points in O(n\log n) time.
I followed the steps of the algorithm and found out that it has O(n Logn) time complexity. Sorting is just finding the lowest X and then in case of equal, find the lower Y. I am not using heap or other sorts initially. On which line, does it has **Log** operation? 
More information can be found from the link provided below.

Link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

```
            points.Sort();
            if (points.Count <= 3)
            {
                return new List<PlaceOfInterest>(points);
            }
            List<PlaceOfInterest> upperHull = new List<PlaceOfInterest>();
            foreach (PlaceOfInterest point in points)
            {
                PlaceOfInterest p2 = point;
                while (upperHull.Count >= 2)
                {
                    PlaceOfInterest pivot = upperHull[upperHull.Count - 2];
                    PlaceOfInterest p1 = upperHull[upperHull.Count - 1];

                    if (Calculation.SignedArea(pivot, p1, p2) <= 0)
                    {
                        upperHull.RemoveAt(upperHull.Count - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                upperHull.Add(p2);
            }
            upperHull.RemoveAt(upperHull.Count - 1);
            List<PlaceOfInterest> lowerHull = new List<PlaceOfInterest>();
            for (int i = points.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                PlaceOfInterest p2 = points[i];
                while (lowerHull.Count >= 2)
                {
                    PlaceOfInterest pivot = lowerHull[lowerHull.Count - 2];
                    PlaceOfInterest p1 = lowerHull[lowerHull.Count - 1];
                    if (Calculation.SignedArea(pivot, p1, p2) <= 0)
                    {
                        lowerHull.RemoveAt(lowerHull.Count - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                lowerHull.Add(p2);
            }
            lowerHull.RemoveAt(lowerHull.Count - 1);
            if (!(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(upperHull, lowerHull)))
            {
                upperHull.AddRange(lowerHull);

            }
            return upperHull;
```

Comment: `O(log n)` does not mean the algorithm contains a logarithm.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does O(log n) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)

Answer (score 2):

`points.Sort()` takes O(N log N) time.

The rest takes O(N) time. (If you did it right -- I didn't check)