# What is the time complexity of following code:

Tags: loops, data-structures, while-loop, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity of following code:

```
int a = 0, i = N; 
while (i > 0) { 
    a += i; 
    i /= 2; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am facing the same problem as my answer is O(N) for the condition to be false when I <= 0 so  N/(2^k) <= 0 , please guide me if I am thinking wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the time complexity of an algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-can-i-find-the-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score -1):

It's complexity will be O(logn).
On every iteration, value of n will be divided by 2, i.e. n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ... 1.

To understand logn [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly)